# How to keep app running while a function is working through in the background?

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there an easy way to run a function while still allowing the app to run?

Currently when I hit a button it runs a function but then freezes everything else until it’s done.

```
while balance < 100 {
    let docRef = db.collection("data").document("names")

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let myDocument = document.data()
            self.balance = myDocument?[name] as! Int
        }
    }

    let base = Int.random(in: 1..<21600)
    //print(coin)
    let guess = Int.random(in: 1..<21600)
    //print(guess)
    if guess == base {
        self.balance += 1
        self.setBalance()
    }

    do {
        sleep(1)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. iOS and Mac both support GCD (Grand Central Dispatch), Apple's queuing and threading model. You'd submit the job to a background queue, and provide a completion handler that you'd invoke on the main thread when the work is done.

It isn't clear what the code you are posting does, the context in which it is used, or how it is time-consuming. You need to edit your question to provide more info:

What is the function that triggers a long-running task that you want to run in the background?

What is the task?

What is the action you want to take once the long-running work is complete?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I left out the sleep command, but essentially all it is this function is ran once a button is hit and the button grays out and the app in unresponsive until it is finished.

Comment: Short answer: Don't do that. Don't ever use sleep on the main thread. It freezes your app during the entire sleep period.

Comment: What is the user experience you are after? Is it that the user taps a button, and it begins a long-running task, and the button is dimmed until the task completes?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you want rather than posting comments in answer to my comments. The goal is to have your question include a complete description of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the context of that code. If it's an IBAction method, include the `@IBAction func functionName()` part.